# Android Scheduled SMS

Tags: android

I am doing some thing like SMS application in android Environment. I have a idea to include scheduled sending sms (IE) send sms in scheduled future. can anyone give me a guidance of how to do scheduled sms. i am new to android, is there any in built functionality to do a scheduled sms. can anyone give me a proper tutorial for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager to schedule your SMS sending or by using Service for background operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SMS Wishes has been around for a long time and is very polished.  Check out what they've done visually as it might give you some ideas.
[SMS Wishes](http://bit.ly/jznFuu)